# Can a NetStream publisher in Flash pause their stream?

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2, netstream

I'm working on a webcam video streaming application utilizing Flash 8 (AS2) and Flash Media Server 3.  Streaming the video live is fairly trivial, but I want to give the publisher the ability to pause their stream, effectively giving the people watching a snapshot instead of realtime video.

NetStream has a pause() method, but the documentation says it only applies to subscribers.  Is there any way to pause the publishing of a stream?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pause:

```
  ns.attachCamera(null);
```

Resume:

```
  ns.attachCamera(Camera.getCamera());
```

Comment: on AMS5.0.3 this actually screws up the recording metadata by the sum of all seconds that the recording has been paused; if you are using it for publishing/subscribing to live data - this is not an issue; if you, however, want recordings with clean metadata - this is not the solution